Mongoose/MongoDB Extremely slow performance on node.js fetching 20k+ documents
I try to find the bottleneck of a node.js statement has to returns 23k documents totaling 3MB. Currently this takes over >60 seconds. The execution time increases with the amount of documents.
const existingPlaces = await Place.find({ username }).select("-username").lean();;

The app is a node.js express app run via ts-node-dev src/app.ts and the code is executed for an api call that needs to return all documents at once. Therefore using a paginator/cursor for the db calls does not make sense.
Possible Bottlenecks and things I tried:

MongoDB (hosted on atlas)



username is indexed.




Running the filter  {'username': '...'}  in MongoDB Compass, shows
17ms fetch and 11ms ixscan execution time and results in 23k
documents.




Exporting all results (on the same network with the Compass app) takes less
than 5s and creates 3 MB large json document.


mongoose hydration or other issues



I already use .lean();




using a raw mongo statement via mongoose.connection.db.collection('places').find({ username }).toArray() did not change the performance


Node/javascript has trouble handling of a 3MB big array



increasing RAM by adding --max-old-space-size=8184 did not improve the performance at all.



Any ideas what I can try to speed this up?
How can I get more debug information here to specify the exact cause?

You should use findOne() instead of find(), assuming username is unique

Try it with the aggregation method.

Since you ruled out network it sounds like another part of your code is blocking the event loop and it's not the query that's eating up the time. Do a performance check on the query : const begin = performance.now(); const existingPlaces = await Place.find({ username }).select("-username").lean(); const end = performance.now(); console.log(`Total: ${end - begin} ms`);. That will tell you how long it took to get your 23k documents.
